# Prove that if $T \subseteq R^m$ is a convex set, then {$x \in R^n: Ax \in T$} is convex

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, convex-analysis

The question itself is pretty explanatory, but I am trying to prove that:

**If $T \subseteq R^m$ is a convex set, then ${x \in R^n: Ax \in T}$ is convex**, where A is a real-valued matrix.

Here's a bit of my logic: if $T$ is convex, so given $(t_1, t_2) \in T$, $\lambda t_1 + (1-\lambda)t_2 \in T$. Let $S$ be a set such that $S = {x \in R^n : Ax \in T}$ and let $s_1,s_2 \in S$. Therefore, $\lambda s_1 + (1 - \lambda)s_2 \in S$.

The problem is that I can't see a way to link the pre-image to the image, meaning, the set of $Ax \in T$ to $x \in S.$  After writing $\lambda s_1 + (1 - \lambda)s_2 \in S$, I have to rewrite these equation changing $u,v$, but I don't know how.

Here's an idea I had: if I have a function $f$ that maps from $T$ to $S$, I have to transform $Ax$ into $x$. Multiplying $Ax$ by the inverse of $A$ would give me $x$, but then I'd have to assume $A$ is invertible and I don't think that should be a restriction here.

---

Disclaimer: This is part of a set of problems I was assigned. Feel free to only give me hints. All help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When taking $s_1,s_2\in S$ we know that $As_1,As_2\in T$, now use convexity of $T$. **The key is that $A$ is linear.**

Answer (score 0):

So you have your element $p = ts_1 + (1-t) s_2$. In order to show that $S$ is convex, you want to show that $p \in S$. The defining propriety of stuff in $S$ is that when you multiply that stuff by $A$, you end up in $T$. Does $p$ satisfy this propriety?

Comment: Should I go: $Ap = A(\lambda s_1 + (1-\lambda )s_2) \implies Ap = \lambda (As_1) + (1-\lambda )(As_2) \implies Ap = \lambda t_1 + (1 - \lambda) t_2$? The problem with this (given what I did is correct), is that both $Ap$ and $ \lambda t_1 + (1 - \lambda) t_2$ belong to $T$. $p$ might belong to $S$, but $Ap$ belongs to $T$. I don't see how that would prove that $p$ belongs that $S$.

Comment: Btw, @Ovi, thank you for helping me out.

Comment: @SethM. My pleasure. What you did is correct, and indeed, the right approach to take. You showed that $Ap$ belongs to $T$. But that's exactly what it means for $p$ to be in $S$! More in detail: $S$ consists of all vectors which, when multiplied by $A$, end up in $T$. You showed that when $p$ is multiplied by $A$, it ends up in $T$. So $p$ is in $S$.

Comment: Thank you for bringing that to light. I am not well-versed in proof writing and I'm left wondering if what I did is what I meant to do. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @SethM. You're welcome. Let me know if I can be of more help.